# Installing OpenJDK on Redhat 7.5 does not create symlink "/usr/java/latest" by default?

Tags: java, java-8, redhat-openjdk

Before we were using Oracle JDK and during its install process it created the symlink "/usr/java/latest"

I notice OpenJDK does not do this by default during its install process - is there a reason why?

A lot of our applications require this path. Now I can just create it manually after the install completes but was just curious why OpenJDK doesn't create it automatically. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you ask the redhat JDK package maintainers?

Answer (score 1):

One basic reason why it's not done is that `/usr/java` is outside the [File Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html). In other words, it's a completely non-standard path. So why use it?

For a distribution like RHEL, this is also an unclear path: will it point to the JDK or JRE? Which version (given that 8, 9, 10, and 11 each introduce incompatibilities)?

OpenJDK in RHEL 7 uses [alternatives(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/alternatives) to provide similar paths. If you haven't modified the `alternative`s, the point to the latest version. For example:

- `/usr/lib/jvm/java` points to the default (latest by default) JDK
- `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0` points to the default (latest by default) JDK 8
- `/usr/lib/jvm/jre` points to the default (latest by default) JRE, and may point to newer versions as they are released.
- `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-openjdk/` points to the default (latest by default) OpenJDK JRE (as opposed to Oracle's or IBM's JRE). It may point to newer (incompatible) versions as they are release.d